# ConnectivityManager error logs

Tags: android

```
11-27 10:30:33.686 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
11-27 10:30:33.688 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
11-27 10:30:36.231 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
11-27 10:30:36.235 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
11-27 10:30:43.929 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
11-27 10:30:43.931 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
11-27 10:30:49.046 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
11-27 10:30:49.048 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
11-27 10:30:51.608 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
11-27 10:30:51.611 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
11-27 10:30:54.170 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
11-27 10:30:54.172 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
11-27 10:30:58.003 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()+ subId=1
11-27 10:30:58.005 31795 31795 D ConnectivityManager: getMobileDataEnabled()- subId=1 retVal=true
```

Just started seeing this in my log files.  Any Ideas?  Its continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this was just an issue with the emulator.  After the next update it went away.